# onJoinedRoom()': no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I checked many times and I can’t find where my mistake is, someone please help, I don’t understand what is happening

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class LobbyManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{

    public Text LogText;

        private void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.NickName = "Player " + Random.Range(1000, 9999);
        Log("Player's name is set to " + PhotonNetwork.NickName);

        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
        PhotonNetwork.GameVersion = "1";
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Log("Connected to Master");
    }


    public void CreateRoom()
    {

        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(null, new Photon.Realtime.RoomOptions { MaxPlayers = 2 });        
    }

    public void JoinRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }

    public override void onJoinedRoom()
    {
        Log("Joined the room");

            PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Game");

    }


    private void Log(string message)
    {

        Debug.Log(message);
        LogText.text += "\n";
        LogText.text += message;

    }


}
```

---

Error: Assets\LobbyManager.cs(40,26): error CS0115: 'LobbyManager.onJoinedRoom()': no suitable method found to override

---

I just can't understand where my mistake or what?? Help plssss guys

Comment: I just got that "Your class has to derive from Photon.PunBehaviour to use these methods. Just change MonoBehaviour to photon.PunBehaviour." here https://answers.unity.com/questions/786607/photon-onjoinedroom-not-working.html Maybe helps.

Comment: I don't even know what you're using, but it's probably because you have a lower case o at the start of method's name...

Comment: OH ! your code OnJoinedRoom(), It should have a Capital letter O at first.

Answer (score 0):

they have changed this in new updates, even if this is an old question, I would like to add the answer I found, as I just came across this question now !

```
public class NetworkManager: MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    ConnectToServer(); 
}
```